# Doubt obtaining the expected value of $x^2$ of a bidimensional harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator

Just for the sake of **context** I'll add a little bit of introductory of the theory we were doing:

Say we are in the context of a bidimensional isotropic harmonic oscillator with an energy found of $2\hbar \omega$ hence $n_x+n_y=1$, which then, we can use separation of variables and suggest a function such that: $$\phi(x,y)=\phi_{n_x}(x)\phi_{n_y}(y)=c_1 \phi_1(x)\phi_0(y)+c_2 \phi_0(x)\phi_1(y)$$

---

**My actual question**: So far so good but now my book pulls out of thin air this expression:

$$\langle x^2\rangle=\langle \phi|x^2|\phi\rangle$$ $$=|c_1|^2 \langle \phi_1(x)|x^2|\phi_1(x)\rangle \langle \phi_0(y)|\phi_0(y)\rangle + |c_2|^2 \langle \phi_0(x)|x^2|\phi_0(x)\rangle \langle \phi_1(y)|\phi_1(y)\rangle$$ which I can't seem to get how you get there? Like no clue, the  only idea I could have is that they use the property $\langle f+g|x^2|h\rangle= \langle f|x^2|h\rangle+\langle g|x^2|h\rangle$ but I have no clue on how to continue even if using that. To be honest I didn't know if I should've posted this in the math website but I decided to post it in here, hopefully there is no problem.

Comment: The calculation is simple. You just need to pay attention to the orthogonality of $\phi_0$ and $\phi_1$: $\int\phi_0(y)\phi_1(y)dy = 0$.

Comment: @Gec you do recognise that I'm asking how to get that expression right? And not how to continue with it. Just in case. But on any case I don't think that helps, I'm still quite stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the expectation value in the position basis:
\begin{align}
\langle x^2 \rangle &= \langle \phi | x^2 | \phi \rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x \int \mathrm{d}y \; \phi^*(x,y) x^2 \phi(x,y) \\
&= \int \mathrm{d}x \int \mathrm{d}y \; x^2\big( c_1^* \phi_1^*(x) \phi_0^*(y) + c_2^* \phi_0^*(x) \phi_1^*(y) \big) \big(c_1 \phi_1(x) \phi_0(y) + c_2 \phi_0(x) \phi_1(y) \big) \\
&= \int \mathrm{d}x \; x^2 \int \mathrm{d}y \; \Big(|c_1|^2 |\phi_1(x)|^2 |\phi_0(y)|^2 + |c_2|^2 |\phi_0(x)|^2 |\phi_1(y)|^2 + c_1^* c_2 \phi_1^*(x) \phi_0^*(y) \phi_0(x) \phi_1(y) + c_2^* c_1 \phi_0^*(x) \phi_1^*(y) \phi_1(x) \phi_0(y) \Big) \\
&= |c_1|^2 \int \mathrm{d}x \; x^2 |\phi_1(x)|^2 \int \mathrm{d}y \; |\phi_0(y)|^2 + |c_2|^2 \int \mathrm{d}x \; x^2 |\phi_0(x)|^2 \int \mathrm{d}y \; |\phi_1(y)|^2 + c_1^* c_2 \int \mathrm{d}x \; x^2 \phi_1^*(x) \phi_0(x) \int \mathrm{d}y \; \phi_0^*(y) \phi_1(y) + c_2^* c_1 \int \mathrm{d}x \; x^2 \phi_0^*(x) \phi_1(x) \int \mathrm{d}y \; \phi_1^*(y) \phi_0(y) \\
&= |c_1|^2 \langle \phi_1| x^2 | \phi_1 \rangle \langle \phi_0 | \phi_0 \rangle + |c_2|^2 \langle \phi_0| x^2 | \phi_0 \rangle \langle \phi_1 | \phi_1 \rangle
\end{align}
In the last step I used that
\begin{equation}
\int \mathrm{d}y \; \phi_0^*(y) \phi_1(y) = \langle \phi_0 | \phi_1 \rangle = 0
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int \mathrm{d}y \; \phi_1^*(y) \phi_0(y) = \langle \phi_1 | \phi_0 \rangle = 0
\end{equation}
because $|\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_0\rangle$ are orthogonal states.